# Can DynamoDB be used for this simple problem?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to understand the limitations of DynamoDB/NoSQL, mostly as a learning exercise.   I came across a problem that is fairly simple in a relational database, but I cannot figure out how to accomplish it in DynamoDB even with full control of rebuilding the tables and indexes.

Problem: Every day everyone in an office chooses one fruit for lunch.   At the end of the week, I just want a list of everyone who ate both an apple and a banana.

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6qSN.png)

I thought employee name should be the PK, day of the week should be the SK.. and Fruit would be an attribute.  But that doesn't seem to work, because you cant query against an attribute.

Is there a way to structure the data to make this work?  Is there another tool like OpenSearch, HiveQL, GraphQL that can help me do what i am trying to do here?

Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) when asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

When you say it's "fairly simple in a relational database", what you mean is it's simple to express, not exactly simple to compute. You're pushing a lot of list intersection work to the database. As your data set grows, the response time for your query will get slower and slower. At some point the database will no longer be able to give you the answer. And while it's consuming CPU (before timing out) you're negatively impacting the load on the relational database server for other users.

With DynamoDB you can't express queries that take unbounded effort to compute or that depend so much on total data set size for their performance characteristics. You have to design a query system up front that doesn't get exponentially slower as the data set grows.

The DynamoDB design then depends on what you know up front. For example, do you know it's always the intersection of an apple and banana? Then during insert of a new food note if the person ate both, and mark them as such on a user metadata item. Use that marker later during the query phase.

Sound like a nuisance? Well, if your data set isn't growing large and/or you don't need reliably fast query performance, then a relational database solves this problem well. Different databases for different purposes.

Comment: I would need to know multiple combinations like apple and banana, or orange and pineapple.  If i were limited to TWO fruits.. i think i could make a new table with a  combined PK  Like "FRUIT#Apple#Banana" as a value, with <Name> as the SK..  and insert into that table every time i saw that a person ate a fruit, when they have already eaten a different fruit.   Then i could query against the PK to get all the SK's (names).   But thats limited to 2 fruits, i couldnt query an arbitrary number of arbitrary fruits.  its OK if the answer is "use RDS". I am trying to learn the limitations of dynamo.

Comment: There, you’ve got the spirit. With DynamoDB you don’t ever do large computations (such as ad hoc joins) at query time.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB also supports `SCAN` and not only `QUERY`.

A simple design for the table is to have the PK to be the name of the person, and the attributes will be the numeric values of the fruits that you can increase every day.

```
UPDATE "FRUIT_COUNTS" 
SET BANANA=BANANA + 1 
WHERE Employee='Bob'
```

Then, at the end of the week, you can run a simple PartiQL query on the table:

```
SELECT * FROM "FRUIT_COUNTS"
WHERE BANANA > 0 AND APPLE > 0
```

Comment: I feel like the usual disclaimer that `SCAN` at scale is very expensive and slow should be added here.

Comment: @Maurice, you are right but the problem mentioned here specifically is not about scale. This solution will be much cheaper than any RDBMS solution.